# How to define specific css, js files for specific route?

Tags: angular

How to define specific css, js files for specific route in angular?

angular.json:

```
... ],
"styles": [
  "src/styles.css"
],
"scripts": [
  "src/app.min.js"
] ...
```

All css or js files are for all routes!

I want to defined
 specific css, js files for specific routes in angular?

Comment: That's how components works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the componet that attends your route.

Change its Encapsulation strategy to NONE:

```
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-style'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
```

All of styles defined in the css of that component will affect to any child component.

Answer (score 1):

A route will take you to a specific component so if you define specific css files for the component, then you will be able to have specific styling for specific routes effectively.

```
@Component({
    stylesUrls: ['path-to-specific-css-file']
})
```

Have a look at the documentation here: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles
For defining styles in components.

Edit: In the ts/js file where the component is defined, you can add specific scripts for the component and any children it may have.